# Site crashes when clicking on photo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I had a popup that came up when clicking on a product photo, which I disabled with display:none.
The photo though is still clickable (it's within an a href) and still crashes my site. 
My question: How can I get rid of the link and make the photo not clickable. I am using a theme  and also have a childtheme. But I just wouldn't know how to properly delete it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can give in your html :

```
html{
      overflow-y: auto!important;
}
```

This works but it's NOT a good approach ! you have to find your js code and delete the code for popup ! The Popup js code  adds overflow:hidden to your html tag.